# What does "political will" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

"The only way to get the political will to grab on to this solution, in the opinion of the Deutsche Bank team, is for something drastic to happen: a stock market sell-off."

And by the way, what does "grab on to" mean?

source: http://www.businessinsider.com/deutsche-bank-stock-market-collapse-fiscal-stimulus-2016-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution referred to by your quote is one proposed by Deutsche bank earlier in the piece, specifically:

> *"...more aggressive fiscal policy, including serious government spending to build infrastructure, hire people, and grow the economy, is needed."*

To implement this requires policy changes and action on the part of the government, in otherwords political change.  The will of the government to enact this is the *"political will"* in your quote.  To "*grab on*" in this context simply means to attach to, or to embrace that solution.  In other words, for the government to agree that this is the solution that they would like to embrace.

In my opinion, the sentence is not particularly well constructed. Normally we wouldn't talk about political will being active and able to do something (to *"grab on"*).  Rather, we might remark that

> "*...in Deutsche Bank's opinion, the only event that would foster the political will to enact that solution is a drastic one: a stock market sell-off.*"